# Add ajax to a simple jquery function

Tags: ajax, jquery, fadein

I am using some simple jquery to show view cart button if something has been added to the cart.

```
if ( $('.cartSummaryItem').text() != 'Shopping cart is empty.' ) {
     $('.account').fadeIn(1000)
};
```

If the cart is empty it show this the text "Shopping cart is empty.", if something is added .account will fadeIn. The problem is I need to refresh the page for this to work, is there a way to do this without refreshing the page with ajax or similar?

Thanks
Nik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the change event doesn't work. Another method is using an Interval.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        setInterval(function () { 
            if ( $('.cartSummaryItem').text() != 'Shopping cart is empty.' ) {
                $('.account').fadeIn(1000)
            };
        }, 10000);
    });
</script>
```

Ofcourse, the interval should be changed to your desired amount. I would only use this if the change doesn't work.. **The change event is prefered**.

Comment: This works, why is it not the preferred way. Does setInterval use more cpu or similar?

Comment: The interval is simply going to check for something every few seconds, minutes or whatever desired miliseconds you have decided to use. Which means, it will keep firing, the change event will only fire when something has changed. In small amounts of intervals, it wouldn't matter.. but a bigger amount might cause performance issues, ofcourse you'll need ALOT intervals running for this to happen..

The change event is better then having 100~500 intervals running on your site :]

Comment: I had a look at the jQuery documentation and... "This event (.change) is limited to <input> elements, <textarea> boxes and <select> elements." Good to know for others looking for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess you have two choices

- Call the javascript code after the user has changed the contents of the cart
- Poll the server for cart changes

If you can, you should probably go for the first choice. Are you in control of the code that changes the contents of the cart?